# QT Creator with multiple qmake

Tags: qt4, makefile, qt-creator

I have already set mutiple qt version in qt creator
But how can I choose the qt version to build?

Thank you

Comment: Your question is really, really unclear. What do you mean by "multiple qmake"?

Comment: Sorry for making you guys confusing. I type it wrongly. It should be multiple qt version. And I was fixed. Just Click Project in the left hand side of the menu and choose the version of qt that I would like to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for making you guys confusing. I type it wrongly. It should be multiple qt version. And I was fixed. Just Click Project in the left hand side of the menu and choose the version of qt that I would like to use.